Display editable material values in property view
First off: I'm sorry if this has been asked before, it most definitely has, but after an hour of searching and experimenting I have to accept I seem to lack the jargon to properly search for it...
That out of the way, I want to "reveal" specific material values in the property view (Shift F7), similar to making a variable public in Unity.
An example: I want to be able to adjust the scale of a Mapping node without having to open the material view.
I am almost certain that this is probably done via custom properties, but I couldn't find out how. Any advice on how it's done or where to find an answer?

You can bring a custom property into a material shader with the Attribute node by using its name in there (case-sensitive, so make sure to spell them exactly the same) or by using the property as a driver.

It sounds as if you may be asking how to use Blender's Custom Properties?

After a bit more trial and error Gordon Brinkmann's explanation worked. I got attribute nodes to work. Here is what I found out:

as Gordon said, spelling is really important

Just as important is setting the correct min, max and default values, i.e. for moving the textures left or right you would obviously have to assign a negative min value

For rotation the best way is to use pi as max value and negative pi for min value

What didn't work was adding custom properties to the material property view. I had to add custom properties to the object itself. That meant setting the attribute node type to "Object".

But that also meant I had to add these properties to ALL objects. The addon Copy Attributes Menu proved invaluable

Make sure to set all the default values before copying to save a lot of work


I hope this helped anyone who also struggled with this admittedly simple function. One day I will tackle drivers, but I was able to do everything with the Attribute node, even if it wasn't the most efficient way.
